# Kinect Finger tracking and Frame rate

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, kinect, tracking

I am working on a finger tracking project using Kinect

But after color segmentation in YUV color space for every frame, the frame rate is reduced from 32 to 6 fps.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either increase your computational power or decrease the size of the problem.

It is often quite effective to first reduce the image-size to whatever minimum size that can still solve your problem before converting color-space and other transformations.